# Access node.js/grunt server through localhost:port on virtual machine

Tags: node.js, virtual-machine, gruntjs

I'm running a node.js server locally on port 9000 through Grunt. I also have a virtual machine running (vmware), but I can't access the node server through that. I've already configured the VM to access my Apache server on the host through localhost, but :9000 gives 'not found'.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Got it! In my project's `Grunt.js` file there was this setting:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    ...
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost'
      },
    }
    ...
  });
```

All I had to do was to change `localhost` to `0.0.0.0` and restart `grunt server`.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation, but with this change, the page flashes up briefly in IE, then 404s.. I must be missing something!

Comment: Wasn't able to get this to work either (on a digital ocean droplet)

Comment: works perfectly for me on VirtualBox using a NAT adapter for IE7, thanks!

Comment: Thank you, thank you.  I have tried every combination out there.  On my Mac (the host machine), I had to use the IP address from system preferences (see @gyrostu's answer below).  Other sources suggested the 10.211.55.2 style addresses - that didn't work for me.  Type that IP address + port on the virtual machine and voila!

Comment: Running into similar issue. What adapter setting are you using in VirtualBox? I've tried NAT as recommended above but didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use your local IP address.

I am on a mac so I go to System Preferences > Network > "Advanced" tab > TCP/IP > IPv4 Address: (ex 10.0.0.3)

Then point your browser to that address using your port number (ex :9000) or whatever you have setup.

Ex: `http://10.0.0.3:9000`

I don't think this is very secure for your local box so make sure to kill the server when you are finished working. Hope this helps.