# Yeoman doesn't broadcast the test server using grunt serve

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I've been looking for quite some time now for this question, but I found nothing.

I scaffold the application using yeoman. I typed `grunt serve` to launch the application. I tried accessing my `computer` using the the ip address

e.g.

```
http://192.168.1.32
```

It correctly show me the default file in my localhost, which is `hello world`, now I want to access the one served by `yeoman`, by adding a port number `:9000`, but it shows me.

```
Webpage is not available,
```

are there extra configurations for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone asks the same question, you can find the answer by examining the Gruntfile.js which tells you to change the host to `0.0.0.0` if you are planning to test it to other devices.

similar question and solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583238/access-node-js-grunt-server-through-localhostport-on-virtual-machine)

Answer (score 1):

There should be no dash in "grunt serve", and that would for the basic generators start the live reload server, which would write output some info on progress in the console, and try to open your default browser when ready.
The server would (again in basic generators) serve at

```
http://localhost:9000
```

What is the output from the console when you start the "grunt serve" ?

Comment: you have noticed the dash, but the answer is not quite that.