# Access Django (back-end) and Grunt (front-end) of a project on a LAN network

Tags: python, django, node.js, gruntjs

I have read these 2 articles which helped me making the project accessible on the network.

1. [For Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144189/making-django-server-accessible-in-lan)
2. [For Grunt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583238/access-node-js-grunt-server-through-localhostport-on-virtual-machine)

I can open both the ends on same IP with different ports on my other computer. The Django server only contains the 404 page and I cannot get past the Login page when accessing the front-end on running `grunt serve` (which I think is maybe because it is not able to access the database)

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: does Django render the login page?  or it's a different login page?

Comment: No. It only shows the 404 page @Anentropic

Comment: so the login page comes from your grunt server?  we need more information about your app and how the two parts fit together to offer any help

Comment: Yes! The page comes from the grunt server but after I input the credentials, it doesn't seem to send any request to the Django server (which I monitor from the terminal) @Anentropic

Comment: I think conceptually you have a problem to run one website from two webservers

Comment: @Anentropic, Is there any way to do it or any different solution in itself?

Comment: I think you probably want to serve the front-end app from Django as well, so they are both running on the same ip:port, and you don't need to use grunt serve at all